# Нужна ли запятая в устойчивом обороте?

Tags: пунктуация

Вроде как в устойчивых оборотах запятые не ставятся. А что насчет "лучше поздно(,) чем никогда" — тут запятая нужна?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я бы не стал причислять эту фразу к устойчивым оборотам, в которых исчезают знаки препинания, поэтому, по-моему, запятую лучше поставить.

Comment: Согласна. Здесь целая поговорка, предложение.

Comment: Именно что целое предложение. Будь оно "нецелым", были бы сомнения.

Answer (score 0):

Во фразеологизмах  не ставится запятая, когда в его составе есть сравнительный оборот (лететь как стрела, голодный как волк...) или деепричастный оборот (бежать сломя голову)